# Full [disclosure]: this tag needs to go

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

[disclosure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/disclosure) 55 questions

This tag runs the gamut for usage

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

- Disclosure agreements
- Disclosure dialogue boxes
- Disclosure buttons (seems to be a usage for [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios))
- [Protecting software from disclosure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55219643/protect-our-saas-platform-from-illegal-content-being-uploaded)

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

Legal advice, no. It's too niche for the other usages (which are on-topic)

> Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

In most cases, no. Adding the word to the title is more helpful.

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

As with #1, no.

Comment: A lot of questions seem to be about disclosure buttons, how bout just retag/close/delete the others and rename the tag to disclosure buttons and update the tag wiki? Should be the easiest way out here

Comment: @BhargavRao That would work too